# Shell Script Alert if connections comming in with the same IP/Port drop

Tags: linux, bash, shell, perl, sh

I'm opening up a new question since my original one was answered and don't want to change the topic.

I am trying to monitor multiple connections coming into two separate ports but with the same IP's

Example

```
netstat -an |grep 000
101.101.101.101:2000        ESTABLISHED
101.101.101.101:2000        ESTABLISHED
101.101.101.102:3000        ESTABLISHED
101.101.101.102:3000        ESTABLISHED
101.101.101.102:3000        ESTABLISHED
101.101.101.102:3000        ESTABLISHED
```

What I'm trying to do is nestat and awk to print column 1 and if 1001.1001.1001.1001:200 isn't in the output 2 times than alert meaning if one goes down still alert that 10.1001.1001.1001 is missing one connection

and also if 10.1001.1001.102:3000 doesn't print exactly 4 times than alert even if it exists 3 times in the netstat output:

Here is my current code which is all good except the IP only has to exist once for the alert to not fail:

```
connections=('101.101.101.101' '101.101.101.102')
running=( $(netstat -an |grep 000 |awk '{print $1}') )
non_running=()
for process_name in ${connections[@]}; do
    if [[ "${running[*]}" == *$process_name* ]]; then
        echo "$process_name is running"
    else
        echo "$process_name is not running"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not quite clear on the requirements. You call the first field `$process_name` but in your netstat output that would be the addr:port combination. Actual output on both Linux and BSDs has the protocol as the first field. Also, you seem to be looking only for established connections but you use `netstat`'s -a switch that makes it print listening sockets, too?

So assuming your output looks like above, I'd do it like this in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %minimum = (
    '101.101.101.101:2000' => 2,
    '101.101.101.102:3000' => 5,
);
my %count;

open my $fh, '-|', 'netstat -an' or die "could not run netstat: $!";
while(<$fh>) {
    next unless /^([0-9.]+:\d+000) /;
    $count{$1}++;
}
close $fh;

while(my ($ip_port, $min) = each %minimum) {
    $count{$ip_port} ||= 0;
    next if $count{$ip_port} >= $min;
    print "$ip_port: need $min connections, found only $count{$ip_port}\n";
}
```

You'll probably have to adapt the regular expression in the read loop. I'd use `netstat -tpn` to get active TCP connections and process names, its output looks like this:

```
tcp        0      0 172.30.252.100:39056    52.216.18.58:80         ESTABLISHED 2000/chrome
```

Comment: Thanks @mbethke ! 
I tried running on my system and get the below errors:

`Use of uninitialized value in numeric ge (>=) at perlconnections.pl line 19.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at perlconnections.pl line 20.
101.101.101.101:2000: need 2 connections, found only
Use of uninitialized value in numeric ge (>=) at perlconnections.pl line 19.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at perlconnections.pl line 20.
101.101.101.102:3000: need 5 connections, found only`

Comment: you are right, I'm only looking for established connections so -an isn't necessary. In my actual environment  I'm  looking for the forth field. I just put it as the first filed to simplify the question. My netstat looks similar to yours:tcp        0      0 172.30.252.100:39056    52.216.18.58:80         ESTABLISHED 2000/chrome         `
`

Comment: You're right, I hadn't considered the case when there were no connections at all. I've added a line to guard against that.

Comment: Thanks @mbethke ! That works. I'm just having an issue with parsing out the 4th column which has the actual IP and not the first one like the example provided. I know how to do this is shell but can't seem to get it to work in perl. This is my actual netstat output:
`tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.151.89.60:46572   ::ffff:10.151.89.57:8030    ESTABLISHED -`
I'm trying to parse out the 4th column which has the IP's to track

Also can you provide an example of if a connection is down to send an email alert with the ip list that's down?

Thanks for all your help!!!

Comment: I tried to use awk in the netstat portion but no luck. Must be regular expressions :)

Comment: Hey @mbethke any suggestions or should i open a new thread since you already answered my initial question. Thanks again for your help!!!